# OSError: [Errno13]

Tags: python, pip

I am trying to install "pip" in my laptop run by Windows 10 OS by typing `pip install notebook` in the command line interface, however I come across the following error message at the end of the installation process:

> ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 13]
> Permission denied: 'C:\Python311\Scripts\pywin32_postinstall.py'
> Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.

Is there anything I can do to overcome this issue? Thanks in advance for any help that can be provided.

Looking for some possible solutions on the internet I tried running the following with the outcomes shown below:

`C:\> chown alberto:alberto python311`

which gives:

> 'chown' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file.

`C:\>chmod 775 Python311`

which gives:

> 'chmod' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file.

Comment: Consider using the --user option or check the permissions.

Comment: chown and chmod are *nix commands; not Windows commands.

Comment: Also, see if you are running any other python app in the same installation env.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the command line as an administrator.
[image]